# Getting an error whilst running an ansible playbook to install forticlient on centos servers

Tags: ansible

Getting error message whilst running an Ansible playbook.

After running it gives error as:

```json
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.dnf) module: description
```

Following is the YAML file.

```yaml
---
- name: Install FortiClient
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Set up Fortinet repository
      yum_repository:
        name: fortinet
        description: configure yum for forticlient
        baseurl: http://repo.fortinet.com/repo/centos/7/os/x86_64/fortinet.repo

    - name: Install FortiClient
      yum:
        name: forticlient
        description: configure yum to insatll forticlient
        state: present

    - name: Restart FortiClient service
      systemd:
        name: forticlient
        description: configure systemd for forticlient
        state: restarted
```

I was expecting it to run but no luck.

Comment: "Unsupported parameters for (<moduleName>) module: <parameterName>" are just syntax errors. As far as I remember non of the listed modules has a parameter description. The description should be in the `name` of the task.

Comment: Error lines does not clear shows in which task it failed, please edit and add above FAILED lines that includes Task line.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into the below suggestions and document links to refer.

A human readable string describing the repository. This option corresponds to the “name” property in the repo file. This parameter is only required if state is set to present.
ref: [yum_repository module example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html#examples)s

systemd module don't have description parameter
ref: [systemd module paramets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html#parameters)

yum module don't have description parameter
ref: [yum module parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameters)

Please double check the baseurl which is not available I've changed with ready to use, where that repo contains name value that I've used in the playbook as Ansible doc suggest to use.

```yaml
---
- name: Install FortiClient
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Set up Fortinet repository
      yum_repository:
        name: fortinet
        description: Fortinet CentOS 8 repository
        baseurl: https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/7.0/centos/8/os/x86_64/fortinet.repo

    - name: Install FortiClient
      yum:
        name: forticlient        
        state: present

    - name: Restart FortiClient service
      systemd:
        name: forticlient        
        state: restarted
```